# Why csv-table can not skip pages in sphinx-doc

Tags: csv, pdf-generation, python-sphinx

I use sphinx to generate PDF files，but when I use csv-table to generate pdf,I found the generated csv-table could not skip pages automatically? How do I fix it?

Comment: You mean tables are not split across pages?

Comment: yes，and how to solve it?@BrechtMachiels

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try the Sphinx builder included with [rinohtype](http://www.mos6581.org/rinohtype/), which offers a drop-in replacement for the LaTeX builder.

rinohtype will split your tables across pages. It can also automatically size table column widths, unlike the LaTeX builder. Another advantage is that rinohtype's PDF output can be styled more easily by means of CSS-like style sheets in case you need this.

(Full disclosure: I am the author of rinohtype)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding the class longtable

```
.. csv-table::
  :file: path-to-csv-file
  :class: longtable
```